# Tensorflow - How to use my own image file after training

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

i am now trying to learn tensorflow so any assistance is appreciated. I followed the mnist code posted on the tensorflow website: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros
The model runs and trains to 99% plus accuracy. I downloaded a png image from the internet of a number one..lets call it 1.png. How do i now input this image into my trained model to determine if it recogonizes it as a one? None of the youtube videos i looked at so far or even the tensorflow page explains how to do this. What do i type to get this image to be checked by the model? There must be a way to pass in a single image to the model after it is trained otherwise there would be no point to reaching the stage of a trained model. The total code i use is below (which is the same code shown on the tensorflow website):

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/mnistworking', graph=sess.graph)


y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b


cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

for _ in range(1000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(17000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

- Restore the model from a saved checkpoint. There are several ways how this can be achieved.
- Load your test image from disk into a numpy array, vectorize and reshape it to be of size `[1, 784]` because this is the shape of your input placeholder defined here: `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])`. Note that `None` in this case stands for a variable batch size, so it is okay to just feed one data point at test time, as you intend to do.
- Next you let the model do its work, i.e. let it predict. For this you need to fetch the node that computes the classification, which seems to be `tf.argmax(y_conv, 1)` in the code you posted. Note that you do not need to feed a label into the model, because you are not performing a training step during test time.

Also, may be this tutorial can be helpful for you: [Tensorflow Mechanics 101](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/mechanics)